# Typeorm - insert object with foreign key using non-primary column

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to know if it is possible to insert an object into the table as shown below using a column other than foreign key with typeorm.

I have these entities:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {

 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number;
 
 @Index()
 @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 30, unique: true })
  username: string;

 @OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user)
 posts: Post[];
}

@Entity()
export class Post {

 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 id: number;
 
 @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 20})
  title: string;
  
  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 240})
  post: string;

 @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.posts)
  @JoinColumn({name: 'user_id'})
  user: User;
}
```

I get the post as object like this:

```json
{
    "title":"First post",
    "post":"Post content",
    "user": {
        "username":"myusername"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to insert the object like this without first looking for the user by its username?

And if the user doesn't exist, it wouldn't be a problem to insert a new one. My point is just not needing to find it before inserting as the username is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the option of 'cascade: true' on your User entity. the addition will be:

```
 `@OneToMany(type => Post, post => post.user, { cascade: true }) posts: Post[];`
```

now after you save the object that you have shared, the user will be created if it doesnt exist

Please read more on the typeorm documentations here: [typeorm docs](https://typeorm.io/#/)

under the cascades section